# Can we fit a piecewise exponential function to coronavirus cases over time?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, predictive-models, curve-fitting

The naive assumption on number of cases, is it is growing exponentially over time. However, different countries has different policies, for example travel ban or staying at home.

So, does it making sense to fit some piecewise model, and each segment is grow exponentially for  coronavirus cases over time?

If yes, can we use basis expansion to do it?

Comment: It makes same sense as fitting any other curve. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Consider instead using a Poisson regression and employing splines of date among the regressor variables.  This will work *extremely* well for the US cases and deaths at this point (if you choose a knot near 2/28/2020 and even just use a linear spline); and, for other countries, will also be quite satisfactory with higher-order splines.

Comment: Answer is yes. So....